# JSON-RPC request handling in Spray (Scala)

Tags: scala, spray, json-rpc

Is any convenient [json-rpc](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) requests handler in [Spray](http://spray.io/)?

Say, there is a route handling jsonrpc2.0 request and marshalling it to some case class via `entity` directive:

```
case class RPCRequest(jsonrpc: String, method: String, params: String, id: Int) 

// .....

  post {
    entity(as[RPCRequest]) { request =>
      complete {
        s"Method: ${request.method}"
      }
    }
  }
```

When application/json request incomes:

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "create", "params": {"token": "dhasgddkgakhadajdasdad237843848234=", "formType": "test2", "channel": "direct", "extra": "adsdasds"}, "id": 3}
```

it's `params` has to be marshalled from json to string and causes an error:

The request content was malformed:
Expected String as JsString, but got {"token":"dhasgddkgakhadajdasdad237843848234=","formType":"test2","channel":"direct","extra":"adsdasds"}

If marshall `params` to certain case class (say, `FormOperation`):

```
abstract class FormOperation
case class FormOperationCreate(order: String, sign: String) extends FormOperation
case class FormOperationOpen(token: String, formType: String, channel: String, extra: String) extends FormOperation
case class FormOperationPhone(token: String, phone: String) extends FormOperation

case class RPCRequest(jsonrpc: String, method: String, params: FormOperation, id: Int)


// .....

  post {
    entity(as[RPCRequest]) { request =>
      complete {
        s"Method: ${request.method}"
      }
    }
  }
```

It works, but as each operation has diffirent parameters, so I can not find out how to let route know which one of `FormOperationCreate`, `FormOperationOpen` or `FormOperationPhone` to choose for marshall into...